# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "___llvm_profile_set_filename", referenced from:

Tags: ios, podspec

I encountered this problem when making the code coverage pod library and executing pod lib lint.

```
phonesimulator/GZCodeCoverageKit.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Binary/GZCodeCoverageKit
    Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
      "___llvm_profile_set_filename", referenced from:
          -[GZCodeCoverageManager registerCoverage:] in GZCodeCoverageManager.o
      "___llvm_profile_write_file", referenced from:
          -[GZCodeCoverageManager enterBackGround] in GZCodeCoverageManager.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    
    ** BUILD FAILED **
```

If there is a big guy to help look at this problem, thank you very much

Currently the pod lib lint does not pass. How do I configure the podspec file